# 401 - Unauthorized error while trying to get profile list from Amazon ads API

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to import data from Amazon ads API in Google App script. I did as per their documentation steps but somehow I am getting 401 - Unauthorized error. It would be very helpful if any of you could help me with this.

Here is Access token generate code  - This is working properly

```
`function myFunction1() {
  var url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token";
  var client_ID = 'clientid';
  var client_secret = 'clientsecret';
  var grant_type = 'authorization_code';
  var code       ='RHwdoHCayhZMjqgSFQPI';
  var scope = 'advertising::campaign_management';
  var redirect_uri = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/AKfycbwWITn81HPdSzw1RwlSz1Gy_Yo56dJdfIxom6C0eij2cSTJwjaZpJrDqCBvMxjp7dPE/exec'; 

 var payload = {
    "grant_type": grant_type,
    "client_id": client_ID,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "code": code, 
    "scope": scope,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
  };

// Log the values before making the request
  Logger.log("code: " + code);
  Logger.log("client_id: " + client_ID);
  Logger.log("redirect_uri: " + redirect_uri);



  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "payload": payload
  };

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      var content = response.getContentText();
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(content);
      Logger.log("Access token obtained successfully: " + jsonData.access_token);
    } else {
      Logger.log("API request failed with response code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("An error occurred: " + error);
  }

}
`
```

Code to retrieve information. - This code is giving me 401 error

```
function myFunction2() {
var baseUrl = "https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles";
var accessToken = "Atza|IwEBIJ4XQ_3m4ftxI6cXvBnr6E8svNJHlvMnhbbW1yCI0fJfOx861qpb-usAx1p-Aa5QK9r8ZXxCa9K26R5fsE6dQMYt6n7l1aPd3RZFK1nKsRurY2eLhAf5WusGF";

var url = "https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles";

var headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
};

var options = {
"method": "get",
"headers": headers,

}
var amazonResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(amazonResponse)
}
```

Here is the steps I followed.

https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/onboarding/create-lwa-app

Comment: Did you already apply for Amazon API access stated in this [article](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/onboarding/apply-for-access) ? Because it stated on their help center that after you create an Amazon Developer account and login to Amazon application, the next step is to apply for access to the Amazon Ads API.

Comment: Yes I have already applied for the access and I have received the approval from their side.